# How to configure Firewall Rules and DNS settings on GCP with VPC Service Controls when using Cloud Composer and Cloud Functions in the same project?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dns

We have troubles with the configuration of two GCP components (the GCP Cloud Composer, the GCP Functions) under VPC Service Controls for a single project. We can configure them separately with VPC Service Controls, but as soon as we add the second component we experience troubles.

Once we have configured the Firewall rules and DNS settings for the Cloud Function, the Composer starts to fail.
The Composer monitoring tool (for webserver, SQL server, etc.) shows that the composer is unhealthy.

What are we doing wrong?

The docs we've used:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls
https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configuring-vpc-sc

For the Composer we use these settings:
3 node
standard machine type
image version: composer-1.16.3-airflow-1.10.15
python: v3
private IP Composer

The APIs what we have enabled for VPC Service Controls:
Restricted Services:
Google Cloud Dataproc API
Cloud Functions API
Google Cloud Pub/Sub API
Cloud SQL API
Google Cloud Storage API
Google Compute Engine API
Google Kubernetes Engine API
Google Container Registry API
Cloud Monitoring API
Cloud Composer API
Artifact Registry API

The FireWall settings (based on the documentation):

| Name | Type | Targets | Filters | Protocols / Ports | Action | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| composer-egress-gke-cluster-all-port | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 10.10.0.0/16 | tcp, udp | Allow | 1000 |
| composer-egress-healthcheck | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16 | tcp:80,443 | Allow | 1000 |
| composer-egress-port53 | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 | tcp:53, udp:53 | Allow | 1000 |
| composer-egress-webserver | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 172.31.251.0/24 | tcp:3306,3307 | Allow | 1000 |
| restricted-google-apis | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 199.36.153.4/30 | tcp:443 | Allow | 1000 |
| composer-deny-all | Egress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 | all | Deny | 2000 |
| composer-ingress-helthcheck | Ingress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16 | tcp:80,443 | Allow | 1000 |
| ingress-iap | Ingress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 35.235.240.0/20 | tcp | Allow | 1000 |
| gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-all | Ingress | gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-node | IP ranges: 10.124.0.0/14 | tcp;udp;esp;ah;sctp;icmp | Allow | 1000 |
| gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-master | Ingress | gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-node | IP ranges: 172.16.8.0/28 | tcp:10250,443 | Allow | 1000 |
| gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-vms | Ingress | gke-europe-west1-composer-dns-xxx-xxx-node | IP ranges: 10.10.0.0/16 | tcp:1-65535;udp:1-65535;icmp | Allow | 1000 |

The DNS settings (based on the documentation):

DNS name: googleapis.com.
Type: Private

| DNS name | Type | TTl(Seconds) | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *.googleapis.com. | CNAME | 300 | restricted.googleapis.com. |
| googleapis.com. | SOA | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 |
| googleapis.com. | NS | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. |

DNS name: cloudfunctions.net.
Type: Private

| DNS name | Type | TTl(Seconds) | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *.cloudfunctions.net. | A | 300 | 199.36.153.4,199.36.153.5,199.36.153.6,199.36.153.7 |
| cloudfunctions.net | NS | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 |
| cloudfunctions.net. | SOA | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. |

DNS name: pkg.dev.
Type: Private

| DNS name | Type | TTl(Seconds) | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *.pkg.dev. | CNAME | 300 | pkg.dev. |
| pkg.dev. | SOA | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 |
| pkg.dev. | NS | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. |
| pkg.dev. | A | 300 | 199.36.153.4,199.36.153.5,199.36.153.6,199.36.153.7 |

DNS name: gcr.io.
Type: Private

| DNS name | Type | TTl(Seconds) | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *.gcr.io. | CNAME | 300 | gcr.io. |
| gcr.io. | SOA | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300 |
| gcr.io. | NS | 21600 | ns-gcp-private.googledomains.com. |
| gcr.io. | A | 300 | 199.36.153.4,199.36.153.5,199.36.153.6,199.36.153.7 |

Thank you for any idea or help what you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile we've figured out the problem:

- The most problematic is that an `A` type DNS record was missing from `googleapis.com.` which contains the IP addresses.
- The second problem was that a firewall rule coming from the documentation of VPC SC settings of the Cloud Function has blocked the communication between:

  - the nodes of the Composer on the subnet
  - between the Worker nodes and the Master node (of the Kubernetes cluster created for composer) which is created automatically in a different project and connected by network peering to the subnet of the Composer workers

The two documentations obviously does not cover this special case when two of these services should be used together. After fixing the issues above it has started to work.

The problems what we still experience:

- it's hard to debug this kind of problem, because the monitoring UI of the composer seems to show the information in non-consistent way
- it's hard to use the StackDriver logs for debugging after enabling it on the subnet, because it's simply too much information and they are logged on "info" level, not on "warning" or "error" level

Answer (score 0):

About the debugging problems in the answer provided by yourself.

**Stackdriver logs problem:**

This problem is already there in the open issues of gcp public issue tracker. You can track the status in the link below[1].

1. https://issuetracker.google.com/135496113

**Composer monitoring panel problem:**

Problem you specified is generic. See if there are any open issues on your problem in the link below [2]. If not, create a new issue.

**You can find or create the gcp product specific issues in the link below.**

2. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

**GCP Cloud composer service release notes link:**

You can periodically check this page for announcements about new or updated features, bug fixes and deprecated functionality of cloud composer service.

3. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes